# Azure VIP Swap to different number of end points

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I'm trying to replace a hosted service with an empty redirect project, however when I try to do so I get the following error;

> *Windows Azure cannot perform a VIP swap between deployments that have a different number of endpoints.*

I believe the only solutions available to me are the following;

1. Point DNS to the staging deployment which after 48 hours of
   propagation delete the production instance and change my DNS to a
   new deployment of the empty redirect project.
2. Delete the production instance and then immediately flip staging.
   This will of course result in downtime.

Unfortunetly changing DNS records isnt an option for me at this stage so unless anyone can suggest an alternative I will have to go with Point #2.

Although my only query with this is once I delete production and flip staging will the new production instance retain the old IP as like I said above im unable to change the DNS records.

Thanks, any queries let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding the additional endpoints to staging through another deployment. Although the application will never use them it allowed me to deploy without downtime.

Alternative solutions are included in my question.

Comment: Another option today would be an in-place upgrade of the production deployment. If you've configured your update domains appropriately you'll avoid downtime and lose only a percentage of your capacity while the upgrade runs.

Answer (score 0):

Once the current deployment in the Production slot is deleted, the IP address should be allocated back to the pool (not available to you).

Comment: Thanks for your reply collier. Its the Public IP that im seeking assurance will not change.

Answer (score 0):

To spare you the hassle of re-deploying and extra 15 min of wait,

you could do it within a minute by deleting PRODCTION slot (if it's applicable !), then you'll do a VIP Swap from 
    PROD: Empty
    STAGING : Your deployment

"OK Deleted the production deployment of cloud service od..."

and end up having

"Successfully swapped the deployments in cloud service od..."

Vincent Thavonekham

Answer (score 0):

This often is a result of having RDP (remote desktop) enabled in one slot but not the other.  RDP creates additional endpoints, thus the error message.  You can either (a) enable RDP on the one that doesn't have it or (b) disable RDP on the one that does have it.  The VIP swap should then work.