# Azure cannot perform a VIP swap between deployments that have a different number of endpoints

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-roles

I'm adding SSL to an application that's currently hosted behind a VIP that cannot change.

I'm attempting to perform a VIP swap after staging a deployment that has an additional endpoint - the one for https.

When I click "swap", I get the error:

> Windows Azure cannot perform a VIP swap between deployments that have
>   a different number of endpoints.

Presumably, this is because I have an additional endpoint added for SSL, which is not consistent with the production slot.

What can I do to make this work, without giving up my VIP?

Comment: I'm not sure if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713665/azure-vip-swap-to-different-number-of-end-points) goes without giving up your vip.

Comment: @rene - that works because he can slap an endpoint into staging to match what's in production.  I need to add an endpoint to production to match what's in staging.

Comment: Have you tried deploying straight to production? As long as you have more than one server running it won't cause downtime as Azure will upgrade one server at a time. Not sure if you will get a similar error, though. And your VIP will be retained.

Comment: I think you can try UPGRADE your prod slot with the additional endpoint. You can use the upgrade button from the portal, or publish through VS by checking the `deployment upgrade` box in the publish wizard.

Comment: @ShaunXu - feel free to make that the answer.  I didn't know about that option from the portal.